# RAML to JAX-RS Doesn't Generate Code(raml-for-jax-rs Eclipse Plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, raml

I have installed the raml-for-jax-rs plugin (https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/eclipseplugin.md) into the Luna and Neon versions of Eclipse.  When I right click on my RAML file and choose "Convert RAML to JAX-RS", the dialog box opens, but when I click "OK", nothing is generated.  In both installations the version of the plugin installed is:

RAML for JAX-RS 1.3.4.201507132324 com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.feature.feature.group    MULESOFT

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong since it's such a simple process.  Does this plugin work for anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a directory for the **Destination folder**. Also, I'm not sure how compatible is the plugin with RAML 1.0, documentation doesn't clarify. Below is a small HelloWorld I used.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I followed all the steps, but when I click OK,the only thing that happens is that the dialog box closes.  No files are generated.

Comment: @sdoca Can you share a sample of the RAML file you're trying to convert?